# remove dynamic unnecessary properties in json object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a todo object
from example, this is my expected object

```
foo ={
  name:'F',
  lastName: 'JOI',
  address:{
    street:'where?'
  }
}
```

and I got all these fields with more properties that I want to remove
for example, this is the object that I receive

```
bar ={
  name:'F',
  lastName: 'JOI',
  address:{
    street:'where?'
  },
  more:'temp',
  prop:'should remove'
}
```

Does there is a way to remove the unnecessary without loop foreach property?
I am using TypeScript if it can help

Comment: Are the unwanted keys dynamic? If not you can use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is to write the code for it directly:

```
const foo: YourType = {
    bar.name,
    bar.lastName,
    bar.address,
    bar.street
};

// Use `foo`
```

That also has the advantage of being typesafe in TypeScript; if you tried to grab a property that isn't a member of `YourType` or that doesn't exist on `bar`, you'll get an error from TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

No.

TypeScript checks that types matches but it does not provide any utility to iterate over type properties, because all the type annotations disappear at compile time.

If you want to delete several keys, this information will have to be present on the "JS layer", because the "TS layer" (types, interfaces, etc) get compiled out, so you'll have to have somewhere a plain JS object or array with all the keys to delete (or to keep). Possible implementations:

```
// keep only the keys you want
const bar = {
  name: bar.name,
  lastName: bar.lastName,
  address: bar.address,
}

// same but with a helper
const keepProps = (src, keys) => Object
  .entries(src)
  .reduce(
    (dst, [key, value]) => {
      if (keys.includes(key)) dst[key] = value;
      return dst;
    },
    {}
  );
const bar = keepProps(foo, ['name', 'lastName', 'address']);

// remove unwanted keys
const bar = { ...foo }; // spread is required to create a different object reference
delete bar.more;
delete bar.prop;
```

About that "no for loop" requirement, it won't be possible, if you want to do several times the same operation, it will either be an explicit loop, or loop hidden by the syntax, like `{ ...obj }` or `Array.filter`.

Comment: while sending post with more keys the call fail, so I need exact fields

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I remove my last paragraph.

Comment: Does this function support nested properties? or just flat object?

Comment: Flat object. For nested props, you can build something pretty similar with [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)